# Custom filename in django image_field

Tags: python, django, django-models

i need to define an custom filename for images uploaded, i have this models:

```
class Personas(model.Models):
     ... some fields here ...
     documento = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Identificacion(model.Models):
     ...some fields here...
     persona = models.ForeignKey('Personas')
     fotos = models.ManyToManyField('FotoPersona',related_name='foto_persona',blank=True,null=True)


class FotoPersona(model.Models):
     persona = models.ForeignKey('Personas')
    foto = models.ImageField(upload_to= CUSTOM_PATH)
```

CUSTOM_PATH must be in the next format:

app_name/persona.documento/file_name

where file_name can be:

perfil

frente

cuerpo_entero

how can i make that?

Answer (score 1):

You can define function which will build required filename and use it in ImageField's upload_to argument:

```
def upload_name(instance, filename):
    return '{}/{}/{}'.format(app_name, instance.persona.documento, filename)

class FotoPersona(model.Models):
    persona = models.ForeignKey('Personas')
    foto = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_name)
```

Comment: and in the argument filename can i pass an especific filename? or this argument take the original filename?

Comment: @jaime it is original filename, but you can override it inside the function.